# set resolution of image loaded on canvas wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, drawing

I am working on  canvas and loading an image on it. How do I set resolution of my image to 640X480 pixels? decodepixelheight and decodepixelwidth not working.

```
   ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(("C:\\Users\\i2v\\Desktop\\GoogleMapTA.jpg"), UriKind.Relative));
        src.DecodePixelHeight = 480;
        src.DecodePixelWidth = 640;
        brush.ImageSource = src;
     //   brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        canvas.Background = brush;
        canvas.Height = src.Height;
        canvas.Width = src.Width;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapImage implements the `System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize` interface. This means that its properties can only be set between calls of its `BeginInit` and `EndInit` methods:

```
var src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\i2v\Desktop\GoogleMapTA.jpg");
src.DecodePixelHeight = 480;
src.DecodePixelWidth = 640;
src.EndInit();

canvas.Background = new ImageBrush(src);
```

Note that you would usually not set `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` at the same time, since this might disrupt the native aspect ratio of the image. Set either one or the other.

Comment: Also note that `C:\...` is not a relative URI.